# Bandwith throttle per connections

Tags: stream

I'm looking for a tool which is able to create a network stream over multiple connections, more soecifically, my ISP throttle's bandwith per connection which is much lower than the bandwith per customer, so I can't benefit of the full bandwith over a single connection. If there would be a tool like netcat able to use multiple underlaying connections, could solve my issue, or if you have better solution....

Update 1,

I own both ends and can run any specific software. both ends are linux systems

Comment: That will only work if you can run custom software at both ends of the connection and will be very OS specific. You've not addresses either of those issues in your question. Further product recommendations, and systems admin are off topic here.

Comment: right, sorry. yes I own both ends and can run any specific software. both ends are linux systems